# CSS reconhecendo variáveis do Javascript dentro do html, é possível?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Por exemplo, tenho um script que pega as coordenadas do mouse:

```js
 function posicaoMouse(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var x = ev.clientX;
        var y = ev.clientY;
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
    }
```

E gostaria que o top e o left fossem definidos pelas variáveis `x`e `y` da function `posicaoMouse`, é possivel?
`<span class="duvida" id="duvida2" style="position: absolute; top:'$x' left:'$y'"> teste </span>`

Comment: Com CSS, não. O que você pode fazer é alterar esses valores via JS, com `element.style.top = y` e `element.style.left = x`, por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi, aí defino por exemplo `var teste= $("#teste");` e depois defino como `teste = element.style...` É isso??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode alterar o valor da propriedade do elemento pelo javascript:

```
let elem = documento.getElementById("duvida2");
function posicaoMouse(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var x = ev.clientX;
    var y = ev.clientY;
    elem.style.top = x;
    elem.style.left = y;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
}
```

Comment: Entendi !!!
Muito obrigado pela explicação Lucas !

Comment: Em 7 minutos poderei aceitar a resposta, novamente, obrigado !

Comment: O que seria o let em `let elem`??

Comment: `let` é similar ao `var`, porem é disponivel somente no escopo que está sendo declarado, é do ECMA6, navegadores mais [novos](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) estão aceitando já.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado !!